# SQL question, DISTINCT returned values in multiple UNION ALL'ed statements

Tags: sql

I have a sql statement that is a union of several queries which all just return keys:

```
SELECT DISTINCT key as KEY FROM tablea WHERE XYZ
    UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT id as KEY FROM tableb WHERE XYZ
    UNION ALL
...
```

My question is that there are some queries that return keys that overlap, and I actually want the final KEY field returned values to be distinct values.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use UNION instead of UNION ALL.

Comment: Or, if you're a mazochist :) then you can surround your query like this:
SELECT DISTINCT KEY FROM (
YOURQUERYHERE
) AS a

Works on SQL Server. But UNION should work.

Comment: Ha... I like it.  Not the mazochist I once was though.

Comment: Thanks a lot Eugene!  Worked great!